# Ruby script to check if a worksheet is present in workbook

Tags: ruby, windows, excel, win32ole

I need to know whether a sheet exists in the workbook or not using ruby.

**code**

```
excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application') 
excel.visible = false   
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(); 
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add() 
workbook.Worksheets("header_new").copy(workbook.Worksheets("header_old"))
```

I need to copy the content of `header_old` into `header_new` only if the later sheet exists else throw an error message.

Comment: Are you angry with Ruby ? :-) BTW in which OS are you now ? Are you using [`win32ole`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html) ?

Comment: To get an answer on stackoverflow, you need to show us what you've tried. It also helps to define terms like "worksheet", to give us a sense of context.

Comment: Angry?? no i need to update some excel data into a workbook in a particular worksheet. if the worksheet is missing i need to throw an error message.I am using windows only.

Comment: @user2818359 tag your question as `window` also. First give us all information you have, then only we can help you out..

Comment: @Ziggy: sorry i am new to Stackoverflow...so dnt knw about the rules..neways i just tried something like this excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')  excel.visible = false        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add();                            worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add()         workbook.Worksheets("header_new").copy(workbook.Worksheets("header_old")) now i need to copy the data of header_old into header_new buit before that i need to check if header_new exists or not

Comment: update this in your post, not in a comment. You asked a good question, but not a proper way.

Comment: Put the code in your question and then asked your need, what you are not being able to figure out by yourself.

Comment: @ArupRakshit : K i am doing it...

Comment: Are you opening a existing excel sheet? where you are looking for if that maned sheet already exist or not. am i right ?

Comment: @rakshit ...yes i am opening the excel sheet.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good blog-post for [`Automating Excel`](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/03/automating-excel-with-ruby.html) using Ruby :

```
# Require the WIN32OLE library
require 'win32ole'
# Create an instance of the Excel application object
xl = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
# Make Excel visible
xl.visible = 1
# Add a new Workbook object
wb = xl.workbooks.add
# Get the first,second Worksheet
ws1,ws2 = wb.worksheets(1),wb.worksheets(2)
# Let rename those sheet
[ws1,ws2].each.with_index(1) { |s,i| s.name = "test_sheet_#{i}" }
# Lets check how many worksheet is present currently
totale_sheet_count = wb.sheets.count

# now let's check if any sheet is having the name, as you are looking for
1.upto(totale_sheet_count).any? { |number| wb.worksheets(number).name == "foo" } # => false
1.upto(totale_sheet_count).any? { |number| wb.worksheets(number).name == "test_sheet_2" } # => true
```

To understand this you first need to look into the method [`#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F), [`#upto`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Integer.html#method-i-upto) and [`#raise`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise).

Here is a final code to meet your needs :

```
require 'win32ole'
excel = WIN32OLE.new( 'Excel.Application' )
excel.visible = true
wb = excel.workbooks.open( "path/to/your_excel.xlsx" )
totale_sheet_count = wb.sheets.count
# below line checking if your excel has any worksheet named as "header_new". If it
# find such a named sheet, Enumerable#any method will return true, otherwise false.
bol = 1.upto(totale_sheet_count).any? { |number| wb.worksheets(number).name == "header_new" }  

begin
  raise( RuntimeError, "Required sheet is not present" ) unless bol
  workbook.worksheets("header_new").copy(workbook.worksheets("header_old")) 
rescue RuntimeError => ex
  puts ex.message
end
```